# rsc bibliography style only printing initials

Tags: bibliographies, drop-cap

I am using \bibliographystyle{rsc} and when I have a lot of authors on a reference, it only prints the initials. I want it to print the surnames as it does usually. Any help appreciated, Thank you.

MWE:

```
 \usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 

\begin{document}

program I want to reference \cite{Gaussian092013} 

\footnotesize{

\bibliography{paper}

\bibliographystyle{rsc}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us the corresponding entry in `paper.bib`?